# How to prevent monitor reconfiguration upon opening of laptop lid

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I damaged my laptop screen but am already currently saving up for a new laptop, so I didn't want to buy a new screen. What I did instead was use a usb monitor I had at my house as a secondary display. I have the monitor set in the control panel as the primary display and have it set to only display on the monitor, not on the laptop screen.

This works reasonably well, however every time I close and reopen my laptop lid it turns the laptop's display back on. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep display settings after opening laptop lid? (it resets to first screen)](https://superuser.com/questions/1231659/how-to-keep-display-settings-after-opening-laptop-lid-it-resets-to-first-scree)

Answer (score 0):

On BIOS there should be a setting to choose External as the starting display output.

Comment: I can only see the top left corner of my laptop screen so I can't use BIOS

Comment: Ack.. perhaps your vendor released an application that can change BIOS settings through Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is quite an old Windows bug which hasn't yet been fixed. Check my dirty solution of this bug [here](https://github.com/nVoxel/WinMDF).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not only add links as answers, try to explain the contents of said Link as it could be changed which would make your answer obsolete.